# In clojure how to lazilly calculate several sub sequences out of a big lazy sequence?

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation

In clojure, I would like to calculate several subvectors out of a big lazy sequence (maybe an infinite one).
The naive way would be to transform the lazy sequence into a vector and then to calculate the subvectors. But when doing that, I am losing the laziness.

I have a big sequence `big-sequence` and `positions`, a list of start and end positions. I would like to do the following calculation but **lazilly**:

```
(let [positions '((5 7) (8 12) (18 27) (28 37) (44 47))
      big-sequence-in-vec (vec big-sequence)]
    (map #(subvec big-sequence-in-vec (first %) (second %)) positions))
; ([5 6] [8 9 10 11] [18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26] [28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36] [44 45 46])
```

Is it feasible?

Remark: If `big-sequence` is infinite, `vec` will never return!

Comment: Is `positions` a fixed list as in your code fragment? If so, you can just use `(vec (take n big-sequence))`, where n = 47 in this case, in your subvec calls.

Comment: @RandyHudson It will solve the issue with the infinite sequence, but it won't keep the laziness.

Comment: `map` is itself lazy, so if you would like just some of the results, the big sequence would only be realized up to the position that are needed. Also, `take`ing some elements doesn't enforce the realization of the entire sequence.

Comment: Are the sub-vectors always sorted? They are in the example. I have assumed so in my solution, as @omiel points out.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking for a lazy sequence of sub-vectors of a lazy sequence. We can develop it layer by layer as follows.

```
(defn sub-vectors [spans c]
  (let [starts (map first spans)                 ; the start sequence of the spans
        finishes (map second spans)              ; the finish sequence of the spans

        drops (map - starts (cons 0 starts))                    ; the incremental numbers to drop
        takes (map - finishes starts)                           ; the numbers to take

        tails (next (reductions (fn [s n] (drop n s)) c drops)) ; the sub-sequences from which the sub-vectors will be taken from the front of
        slices (map (comp vec take) takes tails)]               ; the sub-vectors
    slices))
```

For example, given

```
(def positions '((5 7) (8 12) (18 27) (28 37) (44 47)))
```

we have

```
(sub-vectors positions (range))
; ([5 6] [8 9 10 11] [18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26] [28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36] [44 45 46])
```

Both the spans and the basic sequence are treated lazily. Both can be infinite.

For example,

```
(take 10 (sub-vectors (partition 2 (range)) (range)))
; ([0] [2] [4] [6] [8] [10] [12] [14] [16] [18])
```

Comment: Nice! Note: this assumes that the positions are sorted and (though it is the case in the provided example) I see nothing in the question that implies that.

Comment: @omiel Judging by [OP's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24257372/1562315), the positions need not be sorted, and this solution is invalid.

Comment: Well that's too bad. If the positions are not sorted, you have to keep a reference to the sequence's head. With a big  (potentially infinite) sequence and big positions, it's a potential OutOfMemoryError staring you in the face.

Comment: @omiel Too true. Nor does [OP's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24257372/1562315) or [my other attempt](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24254148/1562315) help: Even if the big sequence is lazy, more and more of it gets realized (or, in my case, moved to the vector) as bigger positions come along.

Answer (score 1):

This works out [@schauho's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24230209/1562315) in a form that is faster than [@alfredx's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24243012/1562315), even [as improved by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24257372/1562315). Unlike [my previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24234752/1562315), it does not assume that the required sub-vectors are sorted.

The basic tool is an eager analogue of [split-at](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/split-at):

```
(defn splitv-at [n v tail]
  (if (and (pos? n) (seq tail))
    (recur (dec n) (conj v (first tail)) (rest tail))
    [v tail]))
```

This removes the first `n` items from `tail`, appending them to vector `v`, returning the new `v` and `tail` as a vector. We use this to capture just as much more of the big sequence in the vector as is necessary to supply each sub-vector as it comes along.

```
(defn sub-spans [spans coll]
  (letfn [(sss [spans [v tail]]
               (lazy-seq
                (when-let [[[from to] & spans-] (seq spans)]
                  (let [[v- tail- :as pair] (splitv-at (- to (count v)) v tail)]
                    (cons (subvec v- from to) (sss spans- pair))))))]
    (sss spans [[] coll])))
```

For example

```
(def positions '((8 12) (5 7) (18 27) (28 37) (44 47)))

(sub-spans positions (range))
; ([8 9 10 11] [5 6] [18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26] [28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36] [44 45 46])
```

- Since `subvec` works in short constant time, it takes linear time in the
  amount of the big sequence consumed.
- Unlike [my previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24234752/1562315), it does not *forget its head*: it keeps
  all of the observed big sequence in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `take` on the big sequence with the maximum of the positions. You need to compute the values up to this point anyway to compute the subvectors, so you don't really "lose" anything.

Comment: I am losing something: I have to realize the big lazy sequence upfront and not only when I need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn pos-pair-to-vec [[start end] big-sequence] 
  (vec (for [idx (range start end)]
            (nth big-sequence idx))))

(let [positions '((5 7) (8 12) (18 27) (28 37) (44 47))
      big-seq (range)]
  (map #(pos-pair-to-vec % big-seq) positions))
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to  write a lazy version of `subvec` using `take` and `drop`:

```
(defn subsequence [coll start end]
  (->> (drop start coll)
       (take (- end start))))

(let [positions '((5 7) (8 12) (18 27) (28 37) (44 47))
      big-sequence (range)]
  (map (fn [[start end]]  (subsequence big-sequence start end)) positions))
;((5 6) (8 9 10 11) (18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26) (28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36) (44 45 46))
```

Comment: You had better put a `vec` at the end of `sub-sequence`, since your question asks for *subvectors*.